# How to use variables from C# application in SSIS package

Tags: c#, ssis

I am new to both VC# and SSIS. But here is my scenario, I have data from multiple projects within a single SQL database i.e. multiproject mode (One SQL database storing data from multiple projects). This data is separated based on proj_ID field.  I am trying to create C# application which pulls this proj_id in one of it's combobox fields and runs the SSIS package on the project after I click on Export data button. Now I want to use this project id in SSIS package so that package dataflow should only execute on that project.

I have added this in C# code and not sure if this is correct:

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Start the SSIS Here    
    try
    {
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
        Package package = null;
        package = app.LoadPackage(@"C:\SSIS_Projects\XXX_Project\XXXX_Project\Package.dtsx", null);
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables myVars = package.Variables;
        myVars["projectroot"].Value = projectroot;
        myVars["path8"].Value =path8;
        myVars["PROJ_NAME"].Value = comboBox1.ValueMember;
        myVars["PROJ_ID"].Value = comboBox2.ValueMember;
        //Excute Package 
        // working Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult results = package.Execute();
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult results = package.Execute(null, myVars, null, null, null);

        if (results == Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure)
        {
            foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError local_DtsError in package.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Package Execution results: {0}", local_DtsError.Description.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (DtsException ex)
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("[Package.dtsx not found in directory]", ex);
    }
}
```

P.S: PROJ_ID is main variable to call in package but I might need projectroot, name and path as well.

If this is correct, then How do I define and use these variable in SSIS package?
how to proceed further in SSIS package? I can guess that I have to write script task but again it will take me lot of time to learn and write. If you can guide me and provide some sample code then it will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Vishal

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember why, but I do remember that when I needed to execute an SSIS package with variables from C#, here is the approach that finally worked for me:

1. Create a job that calls the SSIS package.
2. Create a table that holds the values of the variables used by the package.  The table must also include some kind of "Job Result" column.
3. Include a step at the beginning of the package that reads the values of its variables from the first row in the table that has NULL for JobResult.
4. Include a step at the end of the package that updates the JobResult column in the variables table, with "Success", "Failure" or whatever you want, as long as it's not NULL.
5. In C#, populate the table with the variable values you want, then start the job.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your response. I will try this out. Your procedure is quite clear, still oo you have any reference links to follow real time example?

Comment: No, it was a few years ago, and I don't remember if I even followed any links to create the solution.